# Get JSON data from a different page PHP

Tags: php, json

I have made an "api", I have converted data from my sql table into JSON and that is echoed onto my file "`api.php`", I have "`get.php`" and I would like to get specific bits of data from the JSON on `get.php`. It's not working and just throwing an error however

This is for a contract, I have already tried cURL but it doesn't work

api.php (not included login variables)

```
$dblink = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


      if ($dblink->connect_errno) {
         printf("Failed to connect to database");
         exit();
      }

      $result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM updates LIMIT 3");

      $dbdata = array();

      while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        $dbdata[]=$row;
      }

     echo json_encode($dbdata);
```

and this is what I see on api.php, the JSON is corrected echod i just can't access it.

```
[{"id":"1564343527","title":"title","type":"Server","overview":"overview","added":"a:2:{i:0;s:6:\"added1\";i:1;s:6:\"added2\";}","removed":"a:2:{i:0;s:8:\"removed1\";i:1;s:8:\"removed2\";}","changed":"a:1:{i:0;s:0:\"\";}","date":"2019\/07\/28","time":"09:52:07pm"}]
```

get.php

```
    <?php

    $strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents('api.php');
    var_dump($strJsonFileContents); // show contents

?>
```

error (on get.php)

```
string(610) "connect_errno) { printf("Failed to connect to database"); exit(); } $result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM updates LIMIT 3"); $dbdata = array(); while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $dbdata[]=$row; } echo json_encode($dbdata); ?> "
```

Expected result is for it to echo the page (`api.php`) so i can pick apart the JSON, actual result is an error.

Comment: Looks like your DB credentials are incorrect. The DB connection is failing.

Comment: Edited it, the credentials are correct.

Comment: ^ the problem is still there, nothing changed

Comment: The code fails at `>` which leads me to believe that it's not read as a PHP file but as a html file. Meaning it believes all up to `>` is a tag. Are you sure you start PHP in api.php? `<?php`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the extent of your code,  but I think this can be done simply by including api.php in get.php. There is no need to read the contents of api.php to parse the data.

get.php:

```
<?php
    require 'api.php';

 // api.php is included so $dbdata is in scope here
    var_dump(json_encode($dbdata));
```